# Polylang: translate custom strings in function.php - html structure

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, polylang

So I followed advices to my topic already posted on here, but this one wasn't answered. Polylangs workflow is somewhat like Quantum physics to me so I may missed something...I have added a poll to the woo checkout which is working fine. And also the translation works somewhat BUT ..

**My problem:**
..Polylang ignores the html structure when translating and throws the string out of its div/H2 tag:

I guess the same thing gonna happen to the labels I didn't make it that far. I tried some solutions with an echo which didn't work. Can anyone help me in a direction?

**function.php**

```
add_action('init', function() {
    pll_register_string('thankyou', 'What do you think about the shop?');
    pll_register_string('OceanWP', 'Superb');
});

add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'thank_poll_form', 10 );
function thank_poll_form( $order_id ) {
    echo '<div class="thank-you-poll"><h2>'.pll_e('What do you think about the shop?').'</h2>
        <form id="thankyou_form">
        <label><input type="radio" name="like" value="superb"> Superb</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="like" value="good enough"> Good enough</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="like" value="could be better"> Could be better</label>
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="collect_feedback" />
        <input type="hidden" name="order_id" value="' . $order_id . '" />
        ' . wp_nonce_field( 'thankyou'.$order_id, 'thankyou_nonce', true, false ) . '
        </form></div>';
}
```

**rendered html**

```
**Was hälst du von unserem Shop?**
<div class="thank-you-poll"><h2></h2>
        <form id="thankyou_form">
        <label><input type="radio" name="like" value="superb"> Superb</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="like" value="good enough"> Good enough</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="like" value="could be better"> Could be better</label>
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="collect_feedback">
        <input type="hidden" name="order_id" value="4418">
        <input type="hidden" id="thankyou_nonce" name="thankyou_nonce" value="7624232590"><input type="hidden" name="_wp_http_referer" value="/de/kasse/order-received/4418/?key=wc_order_fKU39RE1qr0iI&amp;utm_nooverride=1">
        </form></div>
```

**EDIT:** I swear to god and his dozen aliases I did try "pll__" before which lead to a critical error. Now desperate, I did try it again and it does what I assumed the translation should do. So "pll__" and not "pll__e". I hope this may help someone so I don't delete this thread.

Comment: I would suggest that you do your changes directly in the WooCommerce thank you template by overwriting it: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/

Comment: Hint: if you want to add an answer to your own question, don't do that by editing your question, but actually post it as an answer. This way you have the option to [mark your question as solved](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: Well it wasn't a typo directly. The docs describe to use "pll__e" and there is a functional difference with "pll__"